Property 'resourceId' not found in \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface
Relatively recently, I started diving into Ratchet and immediately ran into an obstacle that prevents me from realizing my plans. Looking at the documentation, I see that when inheriting the interface for Wamp, it has methods that take "Ratchet\ConnectionInterface" as arguments.
Further, reading the documentation, I discovered that there is a magic "resourceId". Of course, I understood what it is and how it works, however - it is clearly missing from the Connection. Next, I started to get into the code, and it became clear that reading it (and its dependencies) would take quite a long time.
p.s My project is based on Symfony Framework 6.
The question is, what are the alternatives? Is there a definition of resourceId in the latest version at all?

The repository used: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet
Steps taken by me:

Implemented a workaround using spl_object_hash;
Made the implementation by inheritance;
I have read the documentation in detail (possibly outdated), however, I have not seen any new examples;

